# Querying user specific data (incl. population) with react-redux-firebase in one compose method

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-redux, react-native-firebase

i'm working with react-native and have the problem to load only user specific data with `firebaseConnect`. Imagine there are thousends of `todos`, `users` and `doers` and don't want to reference all elements of them.

First of all, a shortcut of my data structure in the real time database:

```
- todos
  |- cleanRoom
  |    |- createdBy: alica
  |    |- title: "Clean the room up"
  |    |- doerList
  |        |- roomCleanerMichael
  |        |- roomCleanerAlica
  |- playBall
       |- createdBy: michael
       |- title: "Play the ball"
       |- doerList
           |- ballPlayerAlica

- users
  |- michael
  |    |- name: Michael
  |    |- age: 22
  |- alica
       |- name: Alica
       |- age: 27

- doers
  |- roomCleanerMichael
  |    |- user: michael
  |    |- status: done
  |- roomCleanerAlica
  |    |- user: alica
  |    |- status: done
  |- ballPlayerAlica
       |- user: alica
       |- status: done
```

I have a view/screen in RN, where all informations should be displayed. For now, i have...

```
const populatesTodoCreator = [{child: 'createdBy', root: 'users'}]

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
  return {
    todos: populate(state.firebase, 'todos', populatesTodoCreator),
    uid: state.firebase.auth.uid
  }
}

export default compose(
  firebaseConnect((props, store) => {
      return [
        {path: 'todos', populatesTodoCreator},
      ]
    }
  ),
  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
)(TodoOverviewScreen)
```

When i log in the application with `firebase.auth.uid = michael`, i only want to reference the list of `todos`, where `michael` participates in as `doer` and populate all `doers` in `doersList` (including the `user` in a specific `doer`), and that all in only one single `compose` method.

So the resulting redux state should look like this, because `michael` is only a `doer` for cleanRoom:

```
- todos
  |- cleanRoom
      |- createdBy
      |    |- name: Alica
      |    |- age: 27
      |- title: "Clean the room up"
      |- doerList
           |- roomCleanerMichael
           |     |- user
           |     |    |- name: Michael
           |     |    |- age: 22
           |     |- status: done
           |- roomCleanerAlica
                 |- user
                 |    |- name: Alica
                 |    |- age: 27
                 |- status: done
```

Is this task possible? If yes, how do i get this done? Any structural suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Populating a list like `doerList` is done by another populate parameter.

Changing the populate array to...

```
const populatesTodoCreator = [
  { child: 'createdBy', root: 'users' },
  { child: 'doerList', root: 'doers' } // populates the whole list of elements
]
```

worked for me.

Querying only the `todos`, where the logged in user is participating in and populating the `user` within the `doer` object (to get the expected result) is another question.

Comment: In the firebaseConnect returned array, you have to pass the parameter in another way.
`{ path: 'todos', populates: populatesTodoCreator }`